# SQL Server: Return list of columns shared by a group of database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inheriting a large report that we would like to automate.  I believe most of the data is in a data warehouse that I can access through SQL Server.  The issue I have is that I do not have a lot of documentation (data dictionary, schema, etc.) and I want to determine which fields are common among several tables.  Normally, when I want to return a list of tables and columns, I would query the information schema.  However, in this case, I'm basically looking for a query that is something like:

```
select table_name, column_name
from (information_schema, others?)
where table_name like 'T_Blah %'
and column_names are equal
```

I realize I can get to this through the object browser, but once I start getting into a larger number of tables, I would like a quick query-based approach to identifying my fields for joining.

I appreciate any help I can get.  I googled this for a while, but I didn't find a solution (or I was oblivious to the fact that I had found one).

Comment: I recommend staying away from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` - here's why: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information-schema-views.aspx

Comment: is there a reason to assume column_names are equal? foreign keys rarely have the same names (e.g. `... on my_table.person_id = person.id`)

Answer (score 1):

As well as information schema you also have the system table syscolumns. Assuming you use the former, something like this should work:

```
select column_name, count(distinct table_name)  
from information_schema.columns  
group by column_name  
having count(distinct table_name) > 1
```

Obviously you could restrict by table name/schema if you wanted to look at a subset

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work after I tweaked it a bit.  I really only cared about columns that appeared in more than one table, so this got me there partially.  The following returns a list of tables and columns only for columns appearing in more than one table:

Comment: Oops  select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where column_name in (select column_name  
from information_schema.columns
where table_name like 'T_Blah'   
group by column_name   
having count(distinct table_name) > 1)
and table_name like 'T_Blah'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood yo correctly, you can try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM (  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN_NAME) Quant
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) A
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T_Blah%' AND Quant > 1
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for sql-server. This is just a query I keep on hand, so it is a little more than you requested. But, I kept it in case you want the extra info :). Just remove it if not.

```
select distinct columns.name, schemas.name + '.' + tables.name  
from sys.columns 
join sys.tables 
    on tables.object_id = columns.object_id 
join sys.schemas 
    on schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
where tables.name like '%blah%'
order by  columns.name, schemas.name + '.' + tables.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will yield the column names and data types in a specified table that also appear in other tables followed by a comma separated list of tables in which they appear:

```
SELECT     COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                   (SELECT     TABLE_NAME
                    FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE     (COLUMN_NAME = CommonColumns.COLUMN_NAME) AND (DATA_TYPE = CommonColumns.DATA_TYPE)
                    FOR XML PATH(''))
                , '</TABLE_NAME><TABLE_NAME>', ', '), '<TABLE_NAME>', ''), '</TABLE_NAME>', '') 
                      AS Tables
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
              FROM          INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE     TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T_Blah%') AS CommonColumns
WHERE     (SELECT     COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
           FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE     (COLUMN_NAME = CommonColumns.COLUMN_NAME) AND (DATA_TYPE = CommonColumns.DATA_TYPE)) > 1
```

To have it do this for all tables, simply remove the `WHERE     TABLE_NAME LIKE 'T_Blah%'`.

Or as Aaron recommends, avoid INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT     ColumnName, sys.types.name AS DataType, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                   (SELECT     sys.tables.name AS TableName
                    FROM         sys.columns INNER JOIN
                                          sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
                    WHERE     (sys.tables.type = 'U') AND (sys.columns.name = CommonColumns.ColumnName) AND 
                                          (sys.columns.system_type_id = CommonColumns.system_type_id)
                    FOR XML PATH(''))
                , '</TableName><TableName>', ', '), '<TableName>', ''), '</TableName>', '') 
                      AS Tables
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT sys.columns.name AS ColumnName, sys.columns.system_type_id
              FROM          sys.columns INNER JOIN
                                              sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
              WHERE      (sys.tables.type = 'U') AND (sys.tables.name LIKE 'T_Blah%')) AS CommonColumns INNER JOIN
                                     sys.types ON sys.types.system_type_id = CommonColumns.system_type_id
WHERE     ((SELECT     COUNT(sys.tables.object_id) AS TableCount
                         FROM         sys.columns INNER JOIN
                                               sys.tables ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.tables.object_id
                         WHERE     (sys.tables.type = 'U') AND (sys.columns.name = CommonColumns.ColumnName) AND 
                                               (sys.columns.system_type_id = CommonColumns.system_type_id)) > 1)
ORDER BY CommonColumns.ColumnName, sys.types.name
```

To get relations by foreign keys use:

```
SELECT     sys.foreign_keys.name AS ForeignKeyName, OBJECT_NAME(sys.foreign_key_columns.parent_object_id) AS ForeignKeyTableName, 
                      ForeignKeyColumns.name AS ForeignKeyColumnName, OBJECT_NAME(sys.foreign_key_columns.referenced_object_id) AS ReferencedTableName, 
                      ReferencedColumns.name AS ReferencedColumnName
FROM         sys.foreign_keys INNER JOIN
                      sys.foreign_key_columns ON sys.foreign_keys.object_id = sys.foreign_key_columns.constraint_object_id INNER JOIN
                      sys.columns AS ForeignKeyColumns ON sys.foreign_key_columns.parent_object_id = ForeignKeyColumns.object_id AND 
                      sys.foreign_key_columns.parent_column_id = ForeignKeyColumns.column_id INNER JOIN
                      sys.columns AS ReferencedColumns ON sys.foreign_key_columns.referenced_object_id = ReferencedColumns.object_id AND 
                      sys.foreign_key_columns.referenced_column_id = ReferencedColumns.column_id
WHERE     (OBJECT_NAME(sys.foreign_key_columns.parent_object_id) LIKE 'T_Blah%') OR (OBJECT_NAME(sys.foreign_key_columns.referenced_object_id) 
                      LIKE 'T_Blah%')
```

Comment: @Jeremy I believe this answer should cover pretty much everything that you want.

Comment: Thank you.  This looks much more eloquent and thorough than what I was using, though the other approach I agreed with above also gets me there.  Much appreciated!